# Laravel Validator: When assigning messages() to object property, property is empty

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I've set up my model with a prepare method and a validate method. The prepare method updates all the models properties with a given array, and returns the validate method which is returning Validator::make`($this->toArray(), array(rules))`; So something like this:

```
Model extends Eloquent{
    public function prepare($newValues){
        $this->value1 = $newValue['value1'];
        // etc....
        return $this->validate();
    }
    public function validate(){
        $v = Validator::make($this->toArray(), array(
                    'value1' => 'required',
                    //etc..
                )
             );
        return $v;
    }
}
```

In my controller, I create a blank errors object, check if the model validates, and if not set an`$errors->errors` property to true and set `$errors->messages` to the validators messages() object, like so:

```
Controller extends BaseController{
    public function update(){
        $newValues = Input::json('newValues');
        $model = Model::find($newValues['id']);
        $modelV = $model->prepare($newValues);

        $errors = new stdClass();

        if($modelV->fails()){
             $errors->errors = true;
             $errors->messages = $modelV->messages();
             return Response::json($errors);
        }else{
             $model->save();
             return $model;
        }
 }
```

I'm returning the data to a front-end that's using Angular. When I `console.log(theReturn)`, I get the object with `errors=true` but the messages property is a blank object. The weird part is if I return the `$modelV->messages()` by itself it shows properly (e.g. `{'value1':['value1 is required']}`). I'm hesistant to say this is a bug but I can't really find out whats's going on. Only when I assign `$modelV->messages()` to another objects property does it turn up blank. I'm going to use a work around in the mean time but I'm wondering if anyone can see something I'm doing wrong, or has experienced this themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use $validator->messages()->toArray()